# AddSignIn Method Missing In ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I created an ASP.NET Core web application and I tried to add the following code for implementing authentication but the AddSignIn method could not be found.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddSignIn("AzureAdB2C", Configuration, // This method is missing
    options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

[AddSignIn](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/d7570bb05ad0576b3595b2def64de883a2088326/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebAppServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L41) is in the namespace `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, which is in the package of the same name.

Have you installed the package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web

Comment: Okay, it seems that this method is only for .NET Core 3.1. I think for .NET Core 2.1 I should use `AddAzureADB2C` but even that is missing from my code. Should I download a separate package for it?